Mix Web API and console app in the same project
I'm creating a .NET 8 app. I'm looking for a hybrid approach where I expose a Web API, but it is able to trigger the same methods from a console app when developing locally.
I will register the appropriate classes in the DI container and trigger them from both places.
Initially I set up 2 projects: the Web API project and a separate console app. But what I wanted to validate with you guys is if I might as well set it up in the Web API boilerplate project as below?
Something like this:
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", true, true);

var config = configuration.Build();

if (config.GetValue<bool>("runAsWebApp"))
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Services.AddControllers();

    var app = builder.Build();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();
}
else
{
    var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);

    using var host = builder.Build();

    await host.Services.GetRequiredService<ConsoleAppEntryPoint>().ExecuteAsync();
}


What would be the benefit from this ? How would you trigger methods from console apps if you don't call them explicitly in console app. I think with swagger and web api you should be fine and test project.

"able to trigger the same methods from a console app when developing locally" - just hit an endpoint that trigger the thing using [tag:curl] or [tag:postman]..

There's nothing wrong with your solution but it's not quite appropriate for your problem. Your actual issue is you want a way of testing your web API. It's not appropriate to test your web app by turning it into a console app.
If you wanted to develop an app that might be a web API in some environments or be a console app where operations are triggered by file import or some other mechanism, then your approach would make sense.
For your scenario you should use an application like Postman API to generate requests to test your app.
